# Accessibility Loading dialog that closes automatically

Tags: html, modal-dialog, accessibility, wai-aria

I have looked all over the ARIA documentation and best practices but couldn't find an answer to this.

Say I have a modal dialog that opens on top of the whole page that shows a spinner. Now I've given the dialog an `aria-label` attribute of `Loading data`

Now this works and the screen reader says:

> Loading data dialog

But when the Dialog dismisses (it is removed) the screen reader doesn't notify the user.

Is there an attribute I can set so that when the dialog is removed the screen reader tells the user or what is the best practice for this example?

Comment: As far as I know when focus is set to back to any item on the main page, the user will know right. Initially they hear loading, later they hear the button/link name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `aria-live` and `aria-relevant` for such interaction. If you apply `aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="all"` to your Dialog's container, it'll be a little talkative about any changes happening in it -- including loading the content (without needing to focus it) and removing it at the end.

Check this page for more options:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-relevant_attribute